# Does watching tv or using computer for a long time in a row effects eyes?

Tags: eye

My dad always forbids me to use computer for long time because it effects our eyesight. But I heard that using computer or watching tv for a long time doesn't effect our eyes. Now which is true?

Answer (score -3):

Your dad is right. LED screen can always make damage to our eyes, especially watching it in a totally dark environment. Watching TV in a dark place for a long time may cause macula in your eye ground. So it is better to take a break every 30 minutes when you have to using TV or computer for works.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. "Watching TV in a dark place for a long time may cause macula in your eye ground." makes no sense to me. The macula is a normal part of the retina, and "ground" isn't a verb I recognize in this context. Please note that this site (unlike many on SE) requires [sources which support answers](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/283/) . Please see the [site tour](http://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help sections](http://health.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about Health.SE.